# Add edge atribute via groupby/itertools

Tags: networkx, pandas-groupby, python-itertools, edges

I hava some data about authors linked to publication IDs. The following script use these co-publications to create a list of edges based on co-authorship:

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools
D = nx.Graph()
D.add_nodes_from(author_affiliations_dataframe['auid'].values)
for i, group in author_affiliations_dataframe.groupby(['pmid'])['auid']:
   # generate all combinations without replacement 
   # from the group of similar column pairs
   for u, v in itertools.combinations(group, 2):           
       D.add_edge(u, v)
```

However, I now want to add the publication year to every edge, since I am interested in the evolution of these networks over time. The year of the publication is linked to the publication IDs and is also available in the author_affiliations_dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I had found a partly solution to my problem:

```
for i, group in author_pmids.groupby(['pmid'])['auid']:
# generate all combinations without replacement 
# from the group of similar column pairs
    for u, v in itertools.combinations(group, 2): 
         edges.append(pd.DataFrame({'pmid': [i], 'left': [u],'right':[v]}))          
edges = pd.concat(edges)
```

The edges dataframe can subsequently be used to create the edges in the graph object.

The only problem is that the code above is inefficient, so further answers proposing a faster solution are appreciated.